# How to fix munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer when calling fclose and overwriting stack variables in C?

Tags: c, file, pointers, memory, cs50

For context this code relates to a CS50 assignment that involves loading a bunch of words from a text-file/dictionary

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 10

unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool ghost(const char *word);
bool memoryoverlap(FILE *ptr, const char *word);


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;


// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1;

// Hash table
//node *table[N];



int main(void)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen("dictionaries/large", "r");
   
    char c;

    long bins[45] = {0};

    int wordcount = 0;

    do
    {
        char *word = malloc(sizeof(char) * (LENGTH + 1));


        if (word == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: Null pointer for word");
            return 2;
        }


        int i = 0;

        while ((c = fgetc(dict)) != EOF)
        {
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }

            if (isalpha(c) || (c = '\'' && i > 0))
            {
                word[i] = c;
                i++;
            }

        }

        if (c != EOF)
        {
            word[i] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", word);
            wordcount++;

            free(word);
        }
        else
        {
            free(word);
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    fclose(dict);

    printf("%i", wordcount);
}

unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int length = strlen(word);

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sum += word[i];
    }

    return sum / length;
}
```

I have a couple questions about this code:

1. Originally I just created the string word by using char `word[LENGTH + 1]`. I went to using malloc because I found that the integer `wordcount` was getting overwritten and losing count as my program was running, and I figured that it may have had something to do with me running out of memory in the stack (hence shifting to using memory from the heap with malloc). I am still a little confused if my reasoning as to why `wordcount` was getting overwritten is correct, however, because `wordcount` has a different scope than the string `word` and I thought that variables with smaller scopes were added to the stack in an "upward" direction (meaning that they should interfere with the heap and not variables like `wordcount` that were in the stack to begin with). I also do not really understand why the program would have felt the need to overwrite memory in the first place, since I thought `word` would just be destroyed/re-created every time the loop iterates (Does the problem come from the fact that the pointer to `word` is random or something and I just iterate so many times it always manages to land on the location of `wordcount`... I don't think this is the case but I might be wrong). Is there a way to avoid this overwrite without using malloc for `word`?
2. After changing from using `char word[LENGTH + 1]` to malloc to make `word`, `wordcount` stopped getting overwritten and started recording the correct count. However, for some reason, my program started returning the error munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer whenever it tries to execute `fclose(dict)` at the end of the file. I am quite confused about this. First, my understanding is that `FILE *dict = fopen(...)` creates a FILE pointer using memory in the stack, so I really don't get why starting to allocate memory for `word` using the heap should suddenly cause problems. Second, my program never gives me munmap_chunk() errors in the loop where I am continuously reading from the dict file. In fact, I don't think the program has ever crashed on me before successfully reading out the file's word. My understanding is that the munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error comes from accidentally altering the value of the pointer, but I cannot figure out where this alteration would occur if everything appears to work okay in the loop. I believe I have also read that uninitialized pointers can cause problems by stealing the FILE pointers memory location, but I don't think (especially now that I'm using malloc) I've left any unitialized pointers anywhere. Does anyone know how I would go about getting fclose() to work?

Comment: Any word of more than 10 letters overruns into your next pointer. You don't fix that with malloc, you just overwrite a different location.

Comment: Here's one problem:  `if (isalpha(c) || (c = '\'' && i > 0))`  You probably want `==` rather than `=` here.  Also this code will fail if any word is longer than 10 characters.  At the very least, you should check for buffer overflow *before* storing to `word[i]`.

Comment: You don't check that you successfully opened the file — you must **always** do that.  If you don't check, `fclose()` will complain (crash) when you pass a null pointer to it.